# Decent places to purchase sounds for sound design?

Tags: libraries, resources, sfx, sound-effects

Where are good, solid places to purchase sounds from on the internet? Nine times out of ten buying CDs/DVDs full of sounds results in many of them not being used or not appropriate... I'm wanting to find a few decent places where I can browse for sounds and purchase only the ones I want.

Of course, a lot of the sound design I want to create myself... But there is times where this isn't possible.

Any ideas for places like this?

Comment: Something I've run into with batched effects is that they're generally already designed, which ends up with them being almost useless to us.  We don't want designed, we want raw!  So, when you're purchasing sounds, make sure they specify that they're raw or unprocessed.  The folks at Designing Sound keep a killer list of Independent SFX Libraries, here: http://designingsound.org/sfx-independence/, most of which are unprocessed sounds (I think BOOM Library is the only one there that sells designed sounds, but they point that out, too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a quite a few.

- Blastwave FX offers [Power Packs](http://www.blastwavefx.com/Download%20Packs/c26/index.html), which you can download (click on the power packs at the bottom of the link). They are $25 each and are categorised by groups of sounds.
- On [SoundSnap](http://www.soundsnap.com) you can download each sounds separately, and browse all you want. You pay for a membership and are allowd X amount of sounds per month.
- [Freesound](http://www.freesound.org) is free and you can often find some really nice sounds.
- [Audio Jungle](http://audiojungle.net/)
- [iStockPhoto](http://www.istockphoto.com/index.php?view=full) has got sounds as well.

I'm sure there are a ton more. But here are a few to get you started.

Comment: The Freesound project has been great. Good resource in the past. I have checked all of the ones above, so it looks like I've seen most of them now. Thank you.

Comment: There's another one that's not too bad called AudioMicro.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.hissandaroar.com

soon!

Comment: Looks great... could you give us more info about it?

Comment: And could this be why a while back you put up a poll on your blog asking our favorite format for sound effects ;-) was wondering if there was something in the pipeline. Lookin forward to checking it out! 

Comment: Aye, I've been researching, planning & working on the site for over a year & its taking what I think is a unique philosophical approach based on the context of how sound editors & sound designers work, based on my experience...

Comment: Sounds exciting! Can't wait...

Comment: Insert drool here. :-)

Comment: just finished first promo vid:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYRqJDoQsbU
http://vimeo.com/10132788

Comment: I'm very jealous and can't wait.  I don't know how you find the time, Tim.  I've got to quit my day job!

Answer (score 1):

Two more:

http://www.soundrangers.com/

http://www.sounddogs.com

Answer (score 1):

http://www.soundmountain.com/

Sound Mountain is a fantastic boutique sound FX Library run by Anne Kroeber, who manages her & Alan Splets library

Comment: What's the cost range of Anne's sound fx library? I've been reading up on her and Alan's recording techniques and that FRAP mic that she has.

Answer (score 0):

[SFXsource Sound Library](http://www.sfxsource.com) ... all pro sounds across 645 subcategories and downloadable as aiff, wav, and .mp3

Comment: This looks like a good one too, I'll keep an eye on this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Look into: www.googootools.com (tools for freelancers) they have links to various sound effects libraries.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

also audiosparx.com.

Answer (score 0):

My fav: www.pond5.com

Answer (score 0):

http://www.findsounds.com/

I'm pretty sure everything on the site is free, but there's a ton of sounds and the search filters are very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.signoaudiodesign.com Sound effects librairies for Native-Instruments Kontakt coming soon.